# How to run a Kubernetes job exactly once

Tags: kubernetes

I have a job with `restartPolicy: Never` and completions and parallelism = 1. However the [spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/jobs/run-to-completion-finite-workloads/#handling-pod-and-container-failures) says: *Note that even if you specify .spec.parallelism = 1 and .spec.completions = 1 and .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never", the same program may sometimes be started twice.*

Can somebody explain why this? And maybe offer a solution that the K8s guys did not think about? :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why

> the same program may sometimes be started twice.

is because of the provided consistency guarantees. In distributed environments, guaranteeing various levels of strictness often comes with a performance trade-off. I might be wrong, but that’s my guess.

Comment: It can be. I would not call it *performance* trade-off, but rather the inconvenience of making the code idempotent.